# Membership testing in conditional operator in mongo

Tags: mongodb, mongoengine

How can I use `$in` (like) operator inside `$cond`? For example, inside a "project" stage I want to create a new field called "category" that is conditional on some other fields (for grouping later): it's value would be `catA` if "test_value" is in the list [1,9] else "catB". For small list I can use set of `$eq` inside "$or".

```
"category": {
                    "$cond": {
                        "if" :{
                            "$or" : [
                                { "$eq" : ["$test_value", 1]},
                                {"$eq" : ["$test_value", 9] }
                            ]
                        },
                        "then": {
                            "$literal" : "catA"
                        },
                        "else": {
                            "$literal" : "catB"
                        }
                    }
```

Is there any way to use something like:

```
                     "if" :{
                                "$in" : {"$test_value", [1,9]}
                            },
                            "then": {
                                "$literal" : "catA"
                            },
                            "else": {
                                "$literal" : "catB"
                            }
                        }
```

I am using mongoengine, and above syntax is not allowed.

Comment: Would be really helpful if you could include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for the above problem where you have for some sample documents, show us the expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do intersection of the field and the list of expected values for that field using [$setIntersection](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/setIntersection/) and check the length of the result. If the length is bigger that 0 then the field has value from the list of expected values.

Try the following query:

```
 db.collection.aggregate([
   {
     $project: {
       category: {     
         $let: {
           vars: {
             resultSize: {
               $size: { $setIntersection: [["$test_value"], [1, 9]] }
             }
           },               
           in: { 
             "$cond": { 
               "if": { "$gt" : ["$$resultSize", 0] },                         
               "then": { "$literal" : "catA" },                         
               "else": { "$literal" : "catB" }                     
             }
           }
         }
       }
     }
   }
 ])
```

Comment: Why not? @user3100115

Comment: `$size: { $setIntersection: [["$test_value"], [1, 9]]` will give `0`

Comment: It works for me. Result depends on the field test_value. It can be either 0 or 1.